# Taking N-samples from each group in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, grouping, sampling

I have a table containing data that has a column named `id` that looks like below:

| id | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 244 | 550 | 1000 |
| 1 | 251 | 551 | 700 |
| 1 | 540 | 60 | 1200 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 19 | 744 | 2000 |
| 2 | 10 | 903 | 100 |
| 2 | 44 | 231 | 600 |
| 2 | 120 | 910 | 1100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to take 50 sample rows per `id` that exists but if less than 50 exist for the group to simply take the entire set of data points.

For example I would like a maximum 50 data points randomly selected from `id = 1`, `id = 2` etc...

I cannot find any previous questions similar to this but have tried taking a stab at at least logically working through the solution where I could iterate and union all queries by `id` and limit to 50:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM schema.table AS tbl WHERE tbl.id = X LIMIT 50) UNION ALL;`

But it's obvious that you cannot use this type of solution because `UNION ALL` requires aggregating outputs from one id to the next and I do not have a list of `id` values to use in place of X in `tbl.id = X`.

Is there a way to accomplish this by gathering that list of unique `id` values and union all results or is there a more optimal way this could be done?

Comment: Are you really using v9.1?

Comment: Mistakenly tagged. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are looking to get 50 (or less) from each group of IDs then you can use windowing -

From question - "I want to take 50 sample rows per id that exists but if less than 50 exist for the group to simply take the entire set of data points."

Query -

```
with data as (
select row_number() over (partition by id order by random()) rn,
* from table_name)
select * from data where rn<=50 order by id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-PwxDXT6).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select a *random sample* for each `id`, then you need to randomize the rows somehow. Here is a way to do it:

```sql
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by random()) as u
  from schema.table
) as a
where u <= 50;
```

Example (limiting to 3, and some row number for each `id` so you can see the selection randomness):

1. setup

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;

CREATE TABLE foo
(
  id int,
  value1 int,
  idrow int
  );

INSERT INTO foo
select 1 as id, (1000*random())::int as value1, generate_series(1, 100) as idrow
union all
select 2 as id, (1000*random())::int as value1, generate_series(1, 100) as idrow
union all
select 3 as id, (1000*random())::int as value1, generate_series(1, 100) as idrow;
```

2. Selection

```sql
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by random()) as u
  from foo
) as a
where u <= 3;
```

Output:

| id | value1 | idrow | u |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 542 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 24 | 86 | 2 |
| 1 | 155 | 74 | 3 |
| 2 | 505 | 95 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 46 | 2 |
| 2 | 422 | 33 | 3 |
| 3 | 966 | 88 | 1 |
| 3 | 747 | 89 | 2 |
| 3 | 664 | 19 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Your description of trying to get the UNION ALL without specifying all the branches ahead of time is aiming for a LATERAL join.  And that is one way to solve the problem.  But unless you have a table of all distinct ids, you would have to compute one on the fly.  For example (using the same fiddle as Pankaj used):

```
with uniq as (select distinct id from test)
select foo.* from uniq cross join lateral 
   (select * from test where test.id=uniq.id order by random() limit 3) foo
```

This could be either slower or faster than the Window Function method, depending on your system and your data and your indexes.  In my hands, it was quite a bit faster even with the need to dynamically compute the list of distinct ids.